# How do I install libgraph in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg

When I run `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 14.04, I get the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
sourabh@sourabh-Inspiron-5520:~$ ^C
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Reboot and try again, another process has a lock on `dpkg`.